# I have problem with id increasing in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.5

I have the methods finishSave and numbers, when I call numbers from finishSave, and put dd() I took increasing id, so what about problem?

I tried `dd($this->prefix_id);` in PhoneNumber class Method numbers

```
protected function finishSave(array $options)
{
    $this->numbers();
    Cache::tags([config('app.env') . '_responsecache'])->flush();
    parent::finishSave($options);
}
```

and numbers method

```
public function numbers()
    {
        dd($this->prefix_id);
    }
```

I expect each time from DB the ID of prefix, but I took increasing id, and how I can get this I cannot understand, so help me

Comment: Sorry maybe it's me... What do you mean by you 'took the increasing id'?

Comment: When I in the blade view change number and press save I can see ``dd($this->prefix_id);``id for example "10", and each time when I update I see 11, 12, 13 and so on, but in the DB it is 10 (prefix_id), I want to take all numbers with prefix_id "10" or something other id, but you can see this error or bug I dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all, occasionly it was my fault, I changed blade file from null to model than it was working, sorry.
I have done like this:

```css
<div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('region_id', 'Регион:', ['class' => 'text-semibold']) !!}
        {!! Form::select('region_id', $regions, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
```

and changed to that:

```css
<div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('region_id', 'Регион:', ['class' => 'text-semibold']) !!}
        {!! Form::select('region_id', $regions, isset($phoneNumber) ? $phoneNumber->phonePrefix->region_id : null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
```